# Image filtering by changing weighted elements along an edge

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, edge-detection, weighted-average

So basically I would like to apply a filter to a binary image that takes a weighted average of the values of the neighboring cells. This part I have set up already.

My problem now is I have an "edge" in my image (which is not the edge of the matrix). I want to take a weighted after of the neighboring elements, but only do so for the particular elements that I'm interested in.

There are two approaches that I know of. Either 1) change the weight of the disk filter when the edge is in proximity to the disk or 2) somehow reflect/mirror the values near the edge to the other side. The problem with 2) is that my edge is not straight and kind of goes everywhere.

Here is an oversimplification of the scenario:

```
bin =  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
         1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
         1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
         1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

mask = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
         1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
         1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
         1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
         1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
         0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
```

I want to apply a filter to `bin` but I only want to take weights of the elements that have a value of 1 in `mask`. I can't necessarily mirror `bin` because of the nonlinearity of the edge, so there must be some way to change to weights of the disk filter.
For example, if the normal disk filter has 20 elements in it, each one would have a weight of 0.05. But let's say we are right up against a flat edge; only half of the values of `bin` in the disk filter have a value of 1 in `mask`. Therefore there would be 10 elements, each with a weight of 0.1. Is there a non-iterative way to apply a filter like this?

Answer (score 1):

One option: use `NaN` (Not a Number) in a pre-processing step:

```
bin(~mask)=NaN;
```

Such that `bin` looks like:

```
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN     0     0     0   NaN     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
   NaN   NaN     0     0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

And then use `nanmean` in your filtering routine. In this way, only non-NaN elements are included in the calculation of the mean which will handle a different number of elements to be averaged.

Example:

```
fun = @(x) nanmean(nanmean(x));
B = nlfilter(bin,[3 3],fun);
```

Result:

```
B =

         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
    0.6667    1.0000    0.8333    0.5000    0.1667         0         0         0
    0.6667    1.0000    0.8889    0.6667    0.3333    0.1111         0         0
    0.6667    1.0000    1.0000    0.8889    0.5556    0.2222         0         0
    0.6667    1.0000    1.0000    0.8889    0.5556    0.2222         0         0
    0.6667    0.8889    0.7778    0.6111    0.3889    0.1667         0         0
    0.6667    0.8333    0.6667    0.3333    0.1667         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: If I'm using `imfilter` with a disk filter derived from `fspecial`, how would I implement `nanmean`?

Comment: @Darrik see my edit for the filtering part. If you need a circle, you can update the size of the bloc (currently 3x3) to the size of your disk filter `h` and use `fun = @(x) nanmean(nanmean(x.*(h>0))`.

Comment: Thanks! Another quick question though, hopefully you can still help me out.
The first result with a normal bloc looks like this:
http://i.imgur.com/ddtBcgz.png which looks good.
But with my circular disk filter, it looks like this:
http://i.imgur.com/B7S2MwH.png
The problem now is that the values in the middle are 0.8 instead of 1 and it also seems to fade off as it approaches the edges. Also, is there any way to apply a 'symmetric' option for the left boundary?